# ANOVA data simplification

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to simplify my data in 3-way ANOVA. My data set concerns Daphnia growth rates in different brands of detergent,daphnia clone type, and types of water.

I did:

```
model1<-aov(Growth.rate~Water*Detergent*Daphnia)
summary(model1)
```

`summary()` shows that there's interaction between `Water:Daphnia` and `Detergent:Daphnia`

I do

```
model2<- aov(Growth.rate~Water+Detergent+Daphnia+Water:Daphnia+Detergent:Daphnia)
anova(model1,model2) ##p=.4
summary(model2)
summary.lm(model2)
```

`summary()` shows me all significant differences. `summary.lm()` gives me specific brands interacting with specific clones.

I don't know where to go from here. Water on its own does not show any significant differences in the mean from the intercept, but I can't just eliminate it right?

Comment: belongs on CrossValidated (voted to close/migrate). Also: what you do in terms of stepwise selection, etc., depends very much on **why** you're doing the analysis - what do you hope to find out?

Comment: Showing the actual model (the summary) would help give you good answers.

Answer (score 0):

So there is no significant difference between model 1 and model 2 since $p = 0.4$. That means you can drop the terms that are in model 1 and not in model 2.

You cannot remove single terms if they are significant in interaction terms. So if you leave water:daphnia in the model water needs to be included as well.

If you want to keep checking to see how many terms you can remove you could consider using the step function in R and using AIC or BIC to do model selection.